# Install to php 8.0 the php8.1 and php8.2 and set for different sites in Ubuntu 22.04 and Apache 2.4.58

Tags: server, apache2, php, cron

At the moment I have running PHP 8.0 with Mautic and Moodle on a VPS with Ubuntu Server 22.04.

I want to install Suite CRM what needs php8.1 and another app who needs php8.2.

1. How to install php8.1 and php8.2. I want to keep my default php8.0 and the applications will initially continue to run under 8.0?
2. How can I set the PHP version for every site/app?
3. About cron jobs: At the moment the cron job in Mautic is e.g. `* * * php /var/www/html/mautic/bin/console mautic:campaigns:trigger`
   How do i set an cron job that it use a special php version? (Mautic and Moodle needs cron jobs)

Here ist my config for `mo.stefan-franz.de`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@stefan-franz.de
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle/
ServerName  mo.stefan-franz.de

<Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
Options +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mo.stefan-franz.de
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My SSL configuration_

```
    root@mautic01:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls -alh
total 44K
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 14 12:19 .
    drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Nov  7 08:31 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K Apr  8  2023 000-default.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.5K Apr  8  2023 default-ssl.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  647 Sep 30 12:40 ma.stefan-franz.de-le-ssl.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  532 Nov 14 12:19 ma.stefan-franz.de.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  626 Oct  8 19:56 mo.stefan-franz.de-le-ssl.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  466 Oct  8 19:56 mo.stefan-franz.de.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  636 Nov  7 08:31 shop.stefan-franz.de-le-ssl.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  474 Nov  7 08:31 shop.stefan-franz.de.conf
```

And here is the SSL config for moodle:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin info@stefan-franz.de
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle/
ServerName  mo.stefan-franz.de

<Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
Options +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mo.stefan-franz.de/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mo.stefan-franz.de/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
```

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: I had to rebuild my server. Mautic wanted also run with php8.1 obviously i made the config right. Don't know why. 
I start now again.

Comment: I update my answer with details about how to edit `php.ini`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use different PHP versions on your sites, you have to use PHP FPM(FastCGI Process Manager).

### 1. Installing php8.1 and php8.2

Some of the PHP versions you want are not in the official repos, so you can use `ppa:ondrej/php` repository:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install PHP FPM and required extensions:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-fpm
sudo apt install php8.1-fpm
sudo apt install php8.2-fpm

sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You also have to install the required PHP extensions by the sites/apps you want to run. For example if your PHP8.2 site need MySQL you will have to install that too:

```
sudo apt install php8.2-mysql
```

### 2. Set the PHP version for every site

Edit your Apache2 vhost configs for each site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. Between `<VirtualHost>` and `</VirtualHost>`, add the following code (replace `8.1` with the version you want for each site):

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

You have to add these line to your `-le-ssl.conf` files too. For example `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mo.stefan-franz.de-le-ssl.conf` should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin info@stefan-franz.de
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle/
ServerName  mo.stefan-franz.de

<Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
Options +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mo.stefan-franz.de/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mo.stefan-franz.de/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### 3. Use a specific PHP version for the cron

The `php` command in your cron is using the CLI version of PHP. You have to install the version specific `php-cli` package. You can use `update-alternatives` to configure which version `php` will use. For example if you want to use PHP 8.2 for `php`, do this:

```
sudo apt install php8.2-cli

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2
```

Alternatively, you can use the command `php8.2` instead of `php` in your cron.

### To make changes to the settings in `php.ini`, you have several different files:

- Sites running PHP FPM 8.2:

  Edit:  `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini`

  After changes to this file, you should restart the FPM service:

  ```
  sudo service php8.2-fpm restart
  ```
- Sites running PHP FPM 8.1:

  Edit:  `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`

  After changes to this file, you should restart the FPM service:

  ```
  sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
  ```
- Sites running PHP FPM 8.0:

  Edit:  `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini`

  After changes to this file, you should restart the FPM service:

  ```
  sudo service php8.0-fpm restart
  ```
- Default for sites without `SetHandler` in their vhost config:

  Edit:  `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`

  After changes to this file, you should restart the Apache2 service:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- When using the command `php` from the cron (replace `8.2` with the version you set in `update-alternatives`):

  Edit:  `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini`

Comment: 3rd attempt - But Moodle didn't recognise php8.1 I made it step by step as you described.

Comment: What do you mean by don't recognize? How are you testing it?

Comment: I made an info php: https://mo.stefan-franz.de/info.php
With that code: <?php phpinfo(); ?>
And in Moodle i can check with php version Moodle works

Comment: @StefanFranz can you edit you question and share the vhost config for mo.stefan-franz.de

Comment: Now am back on the PC for fast response and very much thanks for your support.

Comment: @StefanFranz I see you have HTTPS running on the server. Do you have a different config for the SSL? Have you added the `SetHandler` directive there too?

Comment: Yes i use https of course: https://mo.stefan-franz.de/
I don't know what you mean with a "SetHandler" 
I was able to install Mautic and Moodle with some tutorials and both running stable. But unfortunately i'm a beginner and so i need (if you want help me) a easy to use step by step tutorial for dummies. 

I installed php8.1 this with the modules i need: 
sudo apt install php8.1 libapache2-mod-php8.1 php8.1-common php8.1-gmp php8.1-curl php8.1-intl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xmlrpc php8.1-mysql php8.1-bcmath php8.1-gd php8.1-xml php8.1-cli php8.1-fpm php8.1-zip php8.1-imap php8.1-soap

Comment: You have done well. This is the right way to install the PHP extensions. The problem I am seen is that mo.stefan-franz.de still uses the mod_php, not the `php8.1-fpm`. By `SetHandler` I mean this lines: `<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>`. Add these to the ssl config too and restart the Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: What do you mean with ssl config? And how do i have exactly adjust that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add details about your SSL configuration and the result of: `ls -alh /etc/apache2/sites-available/` ?

Comment: @StefanFranz I updated my answer with details how to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mo.stefan-franz.de-le-ssl.conf`. After the edits, don't forget to restart the Apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support. 
For the special php settings for moodle php8.1 this is the right config file?:  /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini

Comment: @StefanFranz yes

Comment: Success :-))) - It works! 
About cronjob - to be sure: In moodle i had to add a cronjob: crontab -u www-data -e
Before it was: PHP8.0
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null

I changed it to: 
* * * * * /usr/bin/php8.1 /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null

Is that right?

Comment: Question to Mautic: I added a info.php, but i can't access. 
What is the reason?
https://ma.stefan-franz.de/info.php

Comment: @StefanFranz Something is blocking the file. It's hard to tell without more details. For a start you can check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. But this is another questions, so it will be best if you open a new questions. Please, check https://askubuntu.com/tour for more details about how AskUbuntu works.

Comment: Have a problem: Moodle doesn't find the images. The moodle working directory is: /var/www/html/moodledata - could it be, that with php changing also the path to this directory i have anywhere to change?
(i went back to php8.0 because moodle have to run - first i need to find the error)

Comment: In the config.php i found:
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://mo.stefan-franz.de';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/html/moodledata';
Maybe i have to adjust here someting?

Comment: To Moodle: if i set the php8.1 as default php without the proxy_fcgi it works normal. 
So i wait now until Mautic is also able with 8.1 and after that, i change my server to 8.1 for all.