# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS support for PHP 8.2

Tags: 22.04, php

I am trying to upgrade php on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS from 8.1 to 8.2 version, but it seems to be only available is 8.1?
I am using only official default Ubuntu repositories, cause of our internal security policy.

How come there are no 8.2 in official Ubuntu repositories? What should I do to get 8.2 from Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are tied to specific versions of packages. 22.04 will only ever get PHP 8.1. 23.10 has 8.2, and 24.04 will have 8.3. If you want 8.2, then reinstall with Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: Install the PPA for php 8.2 (3rd party ppa so likely not allowed) or upgrade to 23.10 (not an lts so likely not allowed). But it will always be against the internal security policy. So you need to ask the person that enforces this, not us :) If you do not own the machine you need to ask the owner to approve what you need/.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492485/install-to-php-8-0-the-php8-1-and-php8-2-and-set-for-different-sites-in-ubuntu-2 for installing