# Why I got error with held broken packages installing php8.2-dev package?

Tags: updates, php

Adding php8.2-dev package to my kubuntu 22.04  I got error with held broken packages :

```
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x jammy InRelease
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease
Hit:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  appmenu-gtk-module-common jsonlint libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 php-composer-ca-bundle php-composer-metadata-minifier php-composer-pcre php-composer-semver php-composer-spdx-licenses php-composer-xdebug-handler
  php-intl php-json-schema php-react-promise php-symfony-console php-symfony-process php-symfony-string php8.1-intl php8.2-mongodb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php mysql-common mysql-server php-bz2 php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pgsql php-xml php8.2-mcrypt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher# sudo apt install   php8.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to run a command (I found a hint in the net):

```
sudo  aptitude  install   php8.2-dev
```

But the same error ?

In my OS I have :

```
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    apt list --installed  libssl3
    Listing... Done
    libssl3/now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 amd64 [installed,local]
    libssl3/now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 i386 [installed,local]


# dpkg -s   libssl3
Package: libssl3
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 5824
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: openssl
Version: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
 and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
 Internet.
 .
 It provides the libssl and libcrypto shared libraries.
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@alioth-lists.debian.net>
```

How to salve the issue ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**

I try to run commands under root :

```
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/WebsocketLaravel10$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for master:
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/WebsocketLaravel10# apt policy php8.2-common
php8.2-common:
Installed: 8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Candidate: 8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Version table:
*** 8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But still got libssl3 dependecy error :

```
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/WebsocketLaravel10# apt policy php8.2-dev
php8.2-dev:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Version table:
8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/WebsocketLaravel10#  sudo apt install   php8.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
```

**UPDATED BLOCK # 2:**

```
apt policy php8.2-dev
php8.2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     8.2.15-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

?

Comment: Your output strongly suggests that the non-Ubuntu `php8.2-dev` package is the cause. Solve by simply cease trying to install an incompatible package.

Comment: Does it mean that I can not install php8.2-dev anyway ?As far as I remember I installed php  from repository ppa:ondrej/php   . Does it matter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install to php 8.0 the php8.1 and php8.2 and set for different sites in Ubuntu 22.04 and Apache 2.4.58](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492485/install-to-php-8-0-the-php8-1-and-php8-2-and-set-for-different-sites-in-ubuntu-2)

Comment: You would probably need to add a PPA to install a different PHP version than the default.

Comment: Sorry, I did understand. I have php8.2 now and need to add php8.2-dev. What for "different PHP version than the default" ?

Comment: I believe, as @ArturMeinild does, that on 22.04 PHP 8.1 is the default, not 8.2. That means you have 8.2 installed through a PPA, and `php8.2-dev` may not be available. Try `apt policy php8.2-common` and `apt policy php8.2-dev` to verify.

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: You don't need sudo for `apt policy` unless you have other problems. Please give the output of `apt policy php8.2-dev` as previously requested. These commands don't try to fix anything; they give info.

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK # 2 with outout of the command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)